# Angular: Passing data from child1 to parent to child2

Tags: angular

Using angular6.

I have a parent component and 2 child component. I am trying to pass data from child1 component to child2 component as below:

Below is child1 component where I created @Output

```
--Child1--

import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
   @Output() eventClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   //Button click event on child - need to pass some values here, below is an example
   nextClicked() {
    this.eventClicked.emit('from clause');
  }
}
```

Below parent component listens to child1

```
--Parent--

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
       <ct-child1 (eventClicked)="childEventClicked($event)"></ct-child1>
       <ct-child2></ct-child2>
    </div>
</form> 

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {

public clickedEvent: string;

  childEventClicked(event) {
    this.clickedEvent = event;    
  }
}
```

Finally below is child2 component which is trying to listen the value

```
--Child2--

import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child2',
  templateUrl: './child2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child2.component.css']
})
export class Child2Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  @Input() event: string;

  //Button click event on Child2 - But here this.event returns undefined
    ValueFromChild1() {
    alert(this.event);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing above is in the ValueFromChild1() event above in Child2Component the value of this.event is coming to be undefined. Not sure whats missing here or I am not doing
something correctly. I can see the value being passed from Child1 to parent correctly but cant get that value in child2.

Could anyone point whats missing above?

Not sure if I should create a separate question but Apart from this could you also let me know how can I create a model, populate it and then pass it instead of just passing a string as above.

Thanks

--Updated code--

```
--Child1--

import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel } from './data.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
   myModelData = {} as MyModel;
   @Output() eventClicked: EventEmitter<MyModel> = new EventEmitter();
   selectedDdlValue: string = '';
    dropDownChange() {
        if (this.selectedDdlValue == '') {
           this.eventClicked = null;
        }
    }

   //Button click event on child - need to pass some values here, below is an example
   nextClicked() {
    this.myModelData.ddlValue = this.selectedDdlValue;
    this.eventClicked.emit(this.myModelData);
  }
}


--Parent--

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
       <ct-child1 (eventClicked)="childEventClicked($event)"></ct-child1>
       <ct-child2 [event]="clickedEvent" *ngIf="clickedEvent"></ct-child2>
    </div>
</form> 

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {

 public clickedEvent: string;

  childEventClicked(event) {
    this.clickedEvent = event;   
  }
}

--Child2--

import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel } from './data.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child2',
  templateUrl: './child2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child2.component.css']
})
export class Child2Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
     @Input() event: MyModel;


  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not binding any properties between parent and child2....

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Any reason your not using service?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I followed this tutorial to create my code. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Talg123 sorry I am new to this, Is service a better option?

Comment: What do you mean by the model? Do you mean an interface?

Comment: @JosefKatič yes interface sorry.Like I want to pass few dropdown value to interface. And then I would pass that to my child.

Comment: +1 to @Talg123 's comment. This is a perfect use case for having a data service that uses Observables, that child 2 subscribes to. Would scale much better and greatly simplify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `@Input() event: string;` on your `Child2Component` but you're not inputting anything in the template `<ct-child2></ct-child2>`.

Your template needs to look like:

```
<ct-child2 [event]="clickedEvent"></ct-child2>
```

If you want to pass a model to the child component:

```
--YourModel.ts--

export class YourModel {
    foo: string;
}

--Child1--

import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
   @Output() eventClicked: EventEmitter<YourModel> = new EventEmitter();

   //Button click event on child - need to pass some values here, below is an example
   nextClicked() {
    const model = new YourModel();
    model.foo = 'bar';
    this.eventClicked.emit(model);
  }
}

--Parent--

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
       <ct-child1 (eventClicked)="childEventClicked($event)"></ct-child1>
       <ct-child2></ct-child2>
    </div>
</form> 

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {

public clickedEvent: YourModel;

  childEventClicked(event) {
    this.clickedEvent = event;    
  }
}


--Child2--

import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child2',
  templateUrl: './child2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child2.component.css']
})
export class Child2Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  @Input() event: YourModel;

  //Button click event on Child2 - But here this.event returns undefined
    ValueFromChild1() {
    alert(this.event);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this works. One quick question I need to show my child2 only when they clicked that button on child1 otherwise I need to hide it. Is there anyhow in my child2 I can listen to this clicked event

Comment: Try putting an `*ngIf="clickedEvent"` on the template. i.e. `<ct-child2 *ngIf="clickedEvent" [event]="clickedEvent"></ct-child2>`

Comment: This means if clickedEvent has some value it will show and if I do this.clickedEvent = null it should hide the child is it?

Comment: So basically what I am trying to achieve is. If the user clicks next then I show child 2. But when they reset one of the dropdown in child1 I would again hide child 2. So I tried setting  this.clickedEvent = null when they reset the dropdown but it did not hide child2. Sorry let me know if you want me to open another question for this.

Comment: @karen yes, if clickedEvent has a value it will show and if it is set to null it should hide it. I'm surprised it hasn't hidden it when you've set it to null. Update your question with your new code and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @karen see my updated answer for how to use a model.

Comment: thanks I have now implemented with model as well. See my updated post above. But that hide part is still not working. See my child1 component where I set it to null when ddl is reset.

Comment: @karen ah I see. `if (this.selectedDdlValue == '') { this.eventClicked = null; }` - here you are setting the event emitter to null. Instead you need to emit null - `this.eventClicked.emit(null)`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for all the help. Will post new questions further if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By the `@Input()` you are basically creating a new attribute for your component. But in your case it is empty. You need to bind to the `@Input` property like this.

`<ct-child2 [event]="clickedEvent"></ct-child2>`

Or

`<ct-child2 event="{{clickedEvent}}"></ct-child2>`

You can also use a condition here

`<ct-child2 [event]="clickedEvent !== undefined ? clickedEvent : ''"></ct-child2>`

This will check if the value is `undefined` then it will set the `@Input() event` in `ct-child2` to an empty string

The `[]` are used to determine if you will use some property as a value of this attribute you can do this with almost every attribute for example

`<div [attr.id]="id"></div>`

This will bind to normal id attribute specified by `attr.` part.

You can also check the `@Input()` [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be passing the value back up from the child anyway, if the clicked button scenario you mentioned is what you want you should just emit something to tell the parent the button was clicked and then pass the data to child two from the parent. [Nice article on input and output decorators](https://appdividend.com/2018/01/28/angular-input-output-tutorial-example-scratch/) I am currently creating a micro tutorial for this situation for devs in my office.